# Android 3D game, Model and Model animation

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I am starting work on my project for my mobile app class. I have alot of experience with 2d programing but I am newer to 3D. For my project I am planning to do a 3d game for the android os. I have looked at many tutorials but I havent had much luck in finding what I need. I have founded alot of basic info about the needed views and how to draw basic shapes but what I need is the ability to import and animate models. I tried a few libaries such as min3d but they would compile but they would crash when launched on the avd. What are some good libaries that are easy to install that would help me. Otherwise how could I go about writing my model importer and animator. I know those would be very intensive but I would like to try to if I can not find a libary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to dive deep into 3D and don't want to waste your time,
In my opinion you should use some Game Engine like Unity, Marmalade or others.
The reason is - 1. they work, 2. they are cross platform, 3. development probably be much faster.

I wrote a blog about: [How to choose a game engine](http://www.pixishare.org/2012/01/pixibots-are-looking-for-game-engine.html)